# Calculate difference between yesterday' sales using LAG function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, window-functions

I'm trying to get the difference between yesterday's sales with the function LAG
I'm using MySQL, but my problem is that I'm getting null values.

Here's my query

```
select to_char(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as "date", 
item,
brand,
sales
from consolidated_purchases
where purchase_date >='2022-05-05' and purchase_date <'2022-05-07'
LAG(sales,1) over (partition by "date", item, brand order by sales)
```

I'm not sure if I'm using correctly the partition clause.
My goal is to be able to create a report that can be sent automatically just when sales of a particular product are lower than 20% of yesterday's sales.

[image: database sample]

Comment: *Please* don't use images of data. Take a minute to read the many reasons why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2067753

Answer (score 0):

It is quite rare to find a dbms product that allows use of an alias defined IN the select clause to be used by another column in THE SAME select clause. **MySQL does not allow this** but the fix is easy - just don't use that alias, simply copy/paste the detail that the alias refers to. e.g.:

```
SELECT
      to_char(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "date"
    , item
    , brand
    , sales
    , LAG(sales, 1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY  to_char(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
        , item
        , brand ORDER BY sales
        )                                 AS lag_sales
FROM consolidated_purchases
WHERE purchase_date >= '2022-05-05' AND purchase_date < '2022-05-07'
```

Teradata is the only dbms I know of that allows you define an alias (such as your "date") and then re-use that alias in the same select clause. There may well be others (some I may have simply forgotten) but they are a minority. It is easier to always avoid attempting to re-use aliases in the same select clause, unless you know that the dbms you are using explicitly supports this.

I would suggest you try the following however, I'm not sure you need to partition by the "date"

```
SELECT
      to_char(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "date"
    , item
    , brand
    , sales
    , LAG(sales, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY  item, brand 
                          ORDER BY purchase_date) AS lag_sales
FROM consolidated_purchases
WHERE purchase_date >= '2022-05-05' AND purchase_date < '2022-05-07'
```